# Should Symfony's 'bin' directory be ignored by git?

Tags: symfony, gitignore

Running `composer install` in a Symfony Standard Edition application with a requirement for Doctrine will add a folder called 'bin'. The folder is configured in `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
}
```

The `.gitignore` file [that comes with the Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/.gitignore) includes the directory (causing git to ignore the directory and all it's contents). It seems like the 'bin' folder only contains links to files inside the 'vendor' folder. This leads me to think that it's a good idea to ignore the folder and let Composer handle it.

However, the example `.gitignore`s [from GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Symfony2.gitignore) and [in Symfony's docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html#initial-project-setup) doesn't include 'bin'. In fact, I can't really find much about this directory in the official Symfony docs at all, including whether or not it's recommended to keep it out of version control.

Is it indeed recommended to let git ignore this directory and its contents, and is Symfony's documentation simply not up-to-date?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Symfony 3 and later

In the Symfony 3 Standard Edition, the purpose of the `bin` directory has been slightly changed. Binaries from Composer packages (such as `phpunit`) are no longer installed in the `bin` directory, but in `vendor/bin`. Instead, the `bin` directory contains the `console` and optionally some other binaries that come with the Symfony skeleton.

Because these files should be committed to your Git repository, you should no longer have the `bin` directory in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 7):

***EDIT: This is answer is only applicable to Symfony 2. For Symfony 3 and later see Nic Wortels [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43546083) below.***

> Is it indeed recommended to let git ignore this directory and it's contents, and is Symfony's documentation simply not up-to-date?

This is indeed the case. The `bin` directory is the same as the vendor directory, it depends on your requirements. It should be ignored. Except if you are going to put custom files in it (e.g. you move `app/console` to `bin/symfony`), then it should be ignored except from those custom files.

The `Symfony2.gitignore` file from GitHub had it's last update 2 years ago. In those 2 years, a lot of things happend (like using Composer with Symfony2). I wouldn't recommend using it as an example.

The docs were indeed not up-to-date, if you hit the "edit" button in the docs you can update it yourself. I'll be very happy if you do that! :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I will take some time this weekend to send a pull request with an update for the documentation!

Comment: I just submitted the pull request - see https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/3827

Comment: For future reference: note that version 2.5 of the Symfony Standard Edition offers a slightly enhanced directory structure, where `app/console` is indeed moved to the `bin` folder. As Wouter already mentioned, you don't want to ignore the `console` file (or the `symfony_requirements` file that comes with this new directory structure too). Obviously an altered `.gitignore` file comes with this new directory structure as well, so you won't have to worry about it.